# row-level security based on logged in user's team

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to use a big query logged in user's other attributes (example:  team) to restrict the rows in a table. Currenlty we have a row level security like below where in which we are making use of the native function session_user().

Looking to see if we could get something like session_team(). A different BQ Table has the user-team mapping.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ROW ACCESS POLICY example_policy
ON  dataset.tablename
GRANT TO ("group:groupname-group@company.com")
FILTER USING (employee_email <> session_user())
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you perhaps referring to this cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/… Use case is using the session_user() function. It is similar to the query you have posted.

But for group you can review this [use case](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/row-level-security-intro#filter_row_data_based_on_region) that uses the region as group. Possibly can be implemented with the group that similar to your use case.

Diagram in the documentation for reference: [image]

Comment: This solution needs a group created in google groups for each team.  If the number of teams are very less, then it can work. However, if we are looking at tens or hundreds of teams, then having that many groups in google and managing it would be a problem.